# Are Nature Letters still considered primary articles?

Tags: citations, journals

I have an article that I want to link as a primary article. I found a really interesting Nature Letter article and I was wondering if this is categorized as a primary article, since it is a "letter":

http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v508/n7497/full/nature13144.html

What do you folks think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not previously familiar with the distinction between "primary articles" and "secondary articles", but the distinction is explored in [this very helpful link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.up.edu%2Fshowimage%2Fshow.aspx%3Ffile%3D12944&ei=XXrFVLuOEcaUNr33gcgF&usg=AFQjCNHh1ogaFwjBVqD1sGslZuJw2MbL1A&sig2=lZ9WIOvptJgbjs-_-mFqRg&bvm=bv.84349003,d.eXY&cad=rja).  After comparing the paper with this document, it seems clear (even) to me that it is a "primary article": they describe results of a rather massive experiment which has not previously been published, and they contribute their own statistical analysis. I didn't see any evidence of a literature review or anything like that.

Also see how Nature describes its own Letters [here](http://www.nature.com/nature/authors/gta/#a1.2): they are short reports of original research.

Forgive my naivete, but: why does it matter?

Comment: Thanks for the update, and it is mandated I should have all articles I reference to as primary articles in the paper I am writing. I don't know why, but they specified that it must be.

Comment: @Tom: Mandated by whom?  That sounds like it could be an unethical mandate: if you used a secondary source in your research, don't you need to cite it?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I believe that high school and early undergrad "how to write a paper" exercises often ban the use of secondary sources, in order to force students to look at primary sources rather than just remix a set of encyclopedias and the lot.

Comment: @jakebeal: Ah, but in that this pertains only to pre-graduate students, such questions should be off-topic for this site, right?  Also, you seem to be implying that I have just done someone's homework. :(

Comment: Hey guys yes I was a engineering turned med sci student, taking a scientific methods course. I have been sifting through hundreds of papers but I haven't come across these letters before. Sorry if I posted in the wrong area.